'string': invalid statement in installScript ...can't declare string
I'm trying to get info on errors that may be happening when I LaunchApplication in installScript, but get an error when I do exactly what this example shows: store error code from custom action
export prototype CmdExecute(HWND);

function CmdExecute(hMSI)
begin 
    LAAW_SHELLEXECUTEVERB = "runas";
    String returnCodeStr;
end;

When I build, I get, ErrorCode C8025, String: undefined identifier.  When I type string, it suggests the word STRING.  I've tried STRING and String like the example shows but it's always unidentified.    How do I get the installScript to let me define strings?
I want to do what the example at the link shows.
Thanks for any help! I am using InstallShield 2021.

I figured it out.  The string declaration was in the wrong place.  The String and other type/variable declarations go above begin.
function CmdExecute(hMSI)
STRING returnCodeStr;
NUMBER nvSize,returnCode;
begin 
    nvSize=250;
    LAAW_SHELLEXECUTEVERB = "runas";
    returnCode=LaunchApplication("C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/RegAsm.exe",
"pathTo/failename.dll /codebase", "",
SW_NORMAL, WAIT, LAAW_OPTION_WAIT_INCL_CHILD);
     if( returnCode <ISERR_SUCCESS ) then
         MessageBox ("CmdExecute call failed!", SEVERE);
     endif;
     NumToStr(returnCodeStr,returnCode);
     SprintfMsiLog("returnCode="+returnCodeStr);
end;

